# Selecting records from table A based in multiple records in B

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following sales structure. Managers are assigned a salesperson per region but also sell themselves. The table below holds the link between managers and salespersons/regions.

TABLE: MSR

| Manager | Sales | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MA | SA | EAST |
| MA | SB | EAST |
| MA | SB | NORTH |
| MB | SA | WEST |
| MB | SB | WEST |

This table lists the orders that each person scored.

TABLE: ORD

| OrderId | Sales | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MA | EAST |
| 2 | MA | WEST |
| 3 | SA | WEST |
| 4 | SA | EAST |
| 5 | SB | EAST |
| 6 | SB | WEST |
| 7 | MB | NORTH |
| 8 | SB | NORTH |

I want an order output per manager. For example for manager MA it would look like this:

| OrderId | Sales | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MA | EAST |
| 2 | MA | WEST |
| 4 | SA | EAST |
| 5 | SB | EAST |
| 8 | SB | NORTH |

For MB it looks like this:

| OrderId | Sales | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | SA | WEST |
| 6 | SB | WEST |
| 7 | MB | NORTH |

Is there an SQL statement that can produce this result?

Comment: JOIN the tables accordingly. Ask a question when any paticular problem arises.

Comment: what db are you using? do you have the access to ifnull() functions?

Comment: The problem is that I can't do it.

Comment: @dcolazin Yes, I have the ifnull(x,y) function. I'm using db2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for any reason you need to return/use the manager, you can use something like the following:

```
SELECT ORD.*, IFNULL(MSR.Manager,ORD.Sales) as ActualManager 
FROM ORD
LEFT JOIN MSR
 ON (ORD.Sales = MSR.Sales and ORD.Region = MSR.Region)
WHERE IFNULL(MSR.Manager,ORD.Sales) = 'MA'
ORDER BY OrderId
```

Answer (score 2):

The below query would get you the results you want, you would just have to swap out the where to be whatever manager that you were looking for, this returns what you're looking for, for MA.

```
SELECT Distinct A.OrderId, A.Sales, A.Region FROM ORD a 
left join MSR b on (a.Sales = b.Sales OR B.Manager = A.Sales) and a.Region = B.Region 
where B.Manager = 'MA' or A.Sales = 'MA'
order by orderid asc
```

Comment: you don't have to group by, it is a where...

Comment: lol youre totally right @dcolazin 100% overthinking, fixed it.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
With cte_MA as (
Select Distinct sales from mar where manager = 'MA' 
Union 
Select Distinct manager from mar where manager = 'MA' ),
Cte_MB as (
Select Distinct sales from mar where manager = 'MB' 
Union 
Select Distinct manager from mar where manager = 'MB'),
Cte_MAorder as (
Select a orderid, a.sales, a region from ord a inner cte_MA b on a.sales = b.sales),
Cte_MBorder as (
Select a.orderid, a.sales, a.region from ord a inner cte_MB b on a.sales = b.sales)
select *  from cte_MAorder;
Select *  from cte_MBorder;
```

You should run all query with to up select query if you run select * from cte_maorder query you get MA assigned salesperson order list
you run select * from cte_mborder query you get MB assigned salesperson order list

Comment: What if there are 100 managers?

Comment: Thanks, Aman. However, there can be many rows in the MSR table. I hope to find a clever join that can do this in one go.